# jquery surround selected text and image with span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, range, selection

I want to surround selected text and image or texts with multiple tags with span tag in jquery. How can i achieve that, I have seen many examples like the below jsfiddle code. All the examples are done only with text, but now want to surround both text and image with span tag. Thanks in advance

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.format').click(function(){
    var highlight = window.getSelection(),  
    spn = '<span class="highlight">' + highlight + '</span>',
    text = $('.conttext').text(),
    range = highlight.getRangeAt(0),
    startText = text.substring(0, range.startOffset), 
    endText = text.substring(range.endOffset, text.length);

    $('.conttext').html(startText + spn + endText);
});
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BGKSN/40/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to use the [`surroundContents` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range.surroundContents) of the range.

```
$('.format').click(function () {
    var highlight = window.getSelection(),
        spn = $('<span class="highlight" />')[0],
        range = highlight.getRangeAt(0);

    range.surroundContents(spn);
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/BGKSN/181
Demo with image at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/BGKSN/182/

Comment: @Karthikeyan it gets pretty complicated when breaking the selection between partially selected nodes.. I would use the [rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy) plugin